# Nginx search query rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Currently I have my rewrite queries like so

```
  rewrite ^/category/category-name /index.php?route=information/category-name last;
```

This works fine for my pages that are static and i know the name to. The problem i run into is whenever i want to modify my opencart search route

**Current URL**

```
/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=nike
```

**Preffered URL**

```
/search/nike
```

I've tried doing my previous way but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$1 last;
```

The rewrite directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite). And a [useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) for regular expressions.